# Console Error with CCParallaxNode and crash

Tags: console, cocos2d-iphone

I'm getting an error in the console that reads
*Assertion failure in -[CCParallaxNode addChild:z:tag:]*
This is for the code

```
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    node = info;
    voidNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
    [voidNode addChild:node z:2 parallaxRatio:ccp(0.0f, 1.0f) positionOffset:ccp(info.contentSize.width/2, info.contentSize.height/2 - winSize.height)];
    [self addChild:voidNode z:2 tag:kTagNode];
```

Not very familiar with debugging with the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply put there a breakpoint and see what is happening ?  Every time i had such error the problem was trying to add a nil child to the parent (there is an assertation of it in a `addChild` method

Comment: I'm not experienced with using breakpoints and debugging. What line do I set the breakpoint? And what do I do after I set it?

Comment: at the first line for example. then you can say to the debugger to execute one more line. So you can make you program run step by step and see what is happening. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html read more here

Comment: Ok I set a breakpoint for the winSize line, and clicked Build and Debug. A new toolbar pops up that I'm not familiar with. If I press continue, this shows. GDB: Program received signal: "SIGABRT".

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/115-Debugging_in_the_Text_Editor/debugging_in_editor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057-CH4-SW1  Use next step to determine the line where application crashes